# How to use python as a calculator app

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I don't have a calculator app installed on my linux system, however I do have `python3` installed, and I would like to use it as a command line calculator.

How can I use a keyboard shortcut to execute a python3 session and run a script to import all the functions from the math library?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an xfce system, applications can be executed using a keyboard shortcut by adding an application shortcut. To do this, open the settings / control pannel, and navigate to keyboard settings.[image: xfce settings]

Navigate to the Application Shortcuts tab and add a new shortcut command. [image: shortcut command dialog] I have used the "calc" button on my keyboard as the keyboard shortcut for this command.

The command `xfce4-terminal -e 'python3 -i /path/to/script.py'` will execute an `xfce4-terminal` window, and run the command `python3 -i /path/to/script.py`.

`/path/to/script.py` should be replaced by a path to a python script. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/env/python3
from math import *
```

This will allow you to start using `python3` as an interactive session "calculator".

eg; commands such as

```
log(10.0)
```

can be executed immediatly.[image: python calculator mode]

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple to use phyton for calculation like:

```
python3 -c 'print(2+3*0.45)'
```

the result in example 3.35